# Aligning two divs to the bottom of the taller one

Tags: javascript, css, html

[image: mockup]

Above is a mockup of what I want to accomplish.

I have two different rows of divs that need to be aligned to the bottom of the row, where I have a strong grey rule at the bottom of each div. These grey rules should align horizontally.

The biggest issue is that, since this is a WordPress theme, each div needs to be able to expand and contract vertically based on the amount of content. That means that if `.description` on the left gets taller, `.page-title` and `.sidebar` need to adjust to ensure that the grey rules are aligned. This prevents me from using any fixed heights, which I could figure out a system with.

My first solution was using a combination of absolute and relative positioning: use two container divs, `.row-1` and `.row-2`, both with `position: relative`, and add `position: absolute; bottom: 0;`. This doesn't seem to work, though, without assigning a fixed height to each `.row-` div, whether I use floats or left :0;/right: 0; to position the individual divs.

The only other solution I can think of is using JavaScript to get the height of the tallest div and adjust margins appropriately, but I'm reluctant to use JavaScript for style. Is there a better solution that I'm missing?

Comment: I am glad you are avoiding tables, "if one use tables for layout, he/she shouldn't call him/her-self a designer"

Comment: Thanks ajax333221, I think if I can't find a CSS way to accomplish this though I might have to resort to tables...

Comment: there is always a way to layout without the evil tables.

Answer (score 1):

This is a common CSS issue and there is no perfect solution.

The best I know is to the one you talk about : make container ´position: relative´ and children `position: absolute; top:0; bottom:0;`.

Indeed if children are floated, they are out of the flow, and you will need [clearfix](http://www.webtoolkit.info/css-clearfix.html) to make your container to have correct height.

Answer (score 0):

If you need the `.description` div to be of fixed size but also need it to be dynamic for the amount of content then use the css property `overflow:scroll` or `overflow:auto` so that it will give a scroll bar to show the extra content without changing the size of the div.

Also for the sidebar, give it a `float:right` and place it before the row 2 div, this will place it on the right. The row 2 div and the content div will both appear beside it on the left as long as it extends vertically into their way or they have a fixed width.

Answer (score -2):

Why don't you try and use CSS framework they are easily customizable and they are very easy to use. try [960.gs](http://960.gs/) or [blueprintcss.org](http://blueprintcss.org/). there are many other versions available of 960 framework is available.

I personally suggest 960 because it is less complicated than others.

```
<div class="grid_7 prefix_1">
    <div class="grid_2 alpha">
        ...
    </div>
    <div class="grid_3">
        ...
    </div>
    <div class="grid_2 omega">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
<div class="grid_3 suffix_1">
    ...
</div>
```

This is a 4 column with fixed width.

Comment: if people who thinks my answer is not useful they can please comment. so i can improve!

Comment: I think your answer is not useful because you don't provide an explicit answer to this question. If you know a way to design the result needed with one of these framework, please develop.